# Calculate expectation of stochastic integrals

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I am trying to calculate
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\int^t_0 e^{\lambda s}dB_s \int^{t+h}_0 e^{\lambda s}dB_s \right], $$
where $(B_t)_{t\geq 0}$ is a brownian motion, $h>0$ and $\lambda > 0$ is some constant. My attempt was to write
$$\int^t_0 e^{\lambda s}dB_s = \int^{t+h}_0 \mathbb{1}_{0\leq s\leq t}e^{\lambda s}dB_s$$
and use Ito's isometry:
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\int^{t+h}_0 \mathbb{1}_{0\leq s\leq t}e^{\lambda s}dB_s \int^{t+h}_0 e^{\lambda s}dB_s\right]$$
$$=\mathbb{E}\left[\int^{t+h}_0 \mathbb{1}_{0\leq s \leq t}e^{2\lambda s}ds \right],$$
but i am not sure if this is correct.

Comment: Yes, it is correct. Alternatively, you could split up the second stochastic integral (from $0$ to $t$ and from $t$ to $t+h$) and and show that the second part of this integral multiplied by the first integral has zero expectation.

Comment: alright, thanks for the fast response.